# Why am I getting error all arrays must be of the same length?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

I was hoping that this would print a six-bar broken bar chart with 5 colored categories from GUI entries, but I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/idlelib/run.py", line 578, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "/home/jerry/Python_Code/AA Python II Submissions/my_script.py", line 64, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  File "/home/jerry/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 708, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
  File "/home/jerry/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 481, in dict_to_mgr
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
  File "/home/jerry/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 115, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = _extract_index(arrays)
  File "/home/jerry/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 655, in _extract_index
    raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import tkinter as tk

# Define the data as a dictionary
data = {
    'x_values': [],
    'y_values': [(6.0, 2), (8.5, 2), (12.5, 2), (15.0, 2), (19.0, 2), (21.5, 2)]
}

# Define a list of colors and categories for the bars
colors = ('tab:red', 'tab:orange', 'tab:purple', 'tab:blue', 'tab:green')
categories = ('Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3', 'Category 4', 'Category 5')

# Create a GUI interface to get user input for x_values
def get_x_values():
    global data
    x_values = []
    for i in range(len(categories)):
        values_list = []
        for j in range(5):
            x, y = x_values_entry[i][j].get().split(',')
            values_list.append((int(x), int(y)))
        x_values.append(values_list)
    data['x_values'] = x_values
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()

# Create a grid of input boxes for the x_values
x_values_entry = []
for i in range(len(categories)):
    label = tk.Label(root, text=categories[i])
    label.grid(row=i, column=0)
    entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=10)
    entry1.grid(row=i, column=1)
    entry2 = tk.Entry(root, width=10)
    entry2.grid(row=i, column=2)
    entry3 = tk.Entry(root, width=10)
    entry3.grid(row=i, column=3)
    entry4 = tk.Entry(root, width=10)
    entry4.grid(row=i, column=4)
    entry5 = tk.Entry(root, width=10)
    entry5.grid(row=i, column=5)
    x_values_entry.append([entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4, entry5])

# Add a button to submit the x_values and close the GUI
submit_button = tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=get_x_values)
submit_button.grid(row=len(categories), columnspan=6)

# Run the GUI
root.mainloop()

# Add the colors and categories to each row of the DataFrame
for i in range(len(data['x_values'])):
    data['facecolors'] = [colors] * len(data['x_values'])
    data['categories'] = [categories] * len(data['x_values'])

# Create a pandas DataFrame from the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a new figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

# Loop through each row of the DataFrame and plot the broken bar chart
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    ax.broken_barh(row['x_values'], row['y_values'], facecolors=row['facecolors'])

# Create legend entries with color rectangles and category labels
legend_entries = [Patch(facecolor=color, edgecolor='black', label=category) for color, category in zip(colors, categories)]

# Add the legend to the plot
ax.legend(handles=legend_entries, loc='upper right', ncol=5, bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.00))


# Customize the axis labels and limits
ax.set_xlabel('Days')
ax.set_ylabel('Jobs')
ax.set_yticks([7, 9.5, 13.5, 16, 20, 22.5], labels=['#3-actual', '#3-budget',
                                                    '#2-actual', '#2-budget',
                                                    '#1-actual', '#1-budget'])
title = ax.set_title('Tasks and Crew-Days')
title.set_position([0.5, 1.0])               #set title at center
ax.set_ylim(5, 26)
ax.grid(True)

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

Each GUI box should take two comma-separated integers for start and duration of that category. The numbers should get a little larger for each category, so that the colors don't overlap. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Example:]

Comment: You have 6 elements in `data['y_values']`. But `data['x_values']` is the same size as `categories`, which is only 5 elements.

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks Burmar!  I knocked off a y_value and that got rid of the error message but all 5 bars displayed full-length in the green color, any ideas?

Comment: I don't know enough about matplotlib to help you with that part. It should be a different question.